# Link a File to a related object on upload

Tags: apex, trigger, files

How would I go about linking a File to a related object when attached to a record? For example, someone uploads a File to an Opportunity and I then want to automatically link that with the Contract object so it is viewable in both places. I feel like this should be doable within APEX, but if there's an easier method that I'm unaware of I'd be happy to look at that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable within Apex. What you need to do is add a `ContentDocumentLink` object, which is essentially a junction object between `ContentDocument` (the entity representing the File) and an object or user to which it's shared.

When you create a `ContentDocumentLink`, you need to populate four fields:

- `ContentDocumentId`, the Id of the `ContentDocument` you're sharing;
- `LinkedEntityId`, the Id of the object to which you're sharing it;
- `Visibility`, either `'AllUsers'`, `'InternalUsers'`, or `'SharedUsers'`, depending on what kind of visibility you want (if you have Communities);
- `ShareType`, either `'V'` (view only), `'C'` (collaborator), or `'I'` (inferred from the object to which it is attached). I believe I is usually appropriate for files attached to objects.

The [`ContentDocumentLink` reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) is a good source for these constants and more details.

Comment: Okay, that's a good response and helps me understand the backend much better. I poked around in my sandbox and it looks like this could be done with Flow as well for a solution without APEX.

Comment: Also, I wrote a tool to do [bulk attachments](https://github.com/davidmreed/DMRNoteAttachmentImporter) a while back if examples are helpful